# HtmlHelper does not contain a definition for 'ActionLink'

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

Dear I had previously a working project on VS2013 suddenly after a windows update I'm getting errors and my project is not running correctly .

I'm getting the error

```
'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'ActionLink' and no extension method 'ActionLink' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Im not an expert programmer but I read on the net that its something related to upgrading the version of web.mvc and other assemblies/ packages or whatever they are called.

I opened the web.config and it's showing the following:

```
   <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile inherits="TwoFactorWeb.TwoFactorProfile">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
        <add namespace="TwoFactorWeb" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

I tried may things including changing the versions number manually in web.config but this always get the project corrupted some how.

Comment: It seems your MVC version has been updated, Check your GAC_MSIL if still it has the MVC 3.0 in it.

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan I have this is it what you asked for ? c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies\System.Web.Mvc.dll

Comment: Rather then checking the file existence, can you make sure that its version is still 3.0? Just do a right click and check its property and see the details tab.

Comment: Also check 'System.Web.WebPages' version and it should be v1.0

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan in the references drop down list I right clicked the MVC and select properties and it's stating the version 3.0.0.0 is this the info you asked for ? and the Webpages version is 2.0.0.0

Comment: Yes so it seems right there, Can you also check the reference of 'System.Web.WebPages'?

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan the System.Web.Webpages is showing 2.0.0.0 in it's properties

Comment: Yeah, now this is the problem it should be 1.0, Check the following path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages" and it should contains two folders v1.0 and v2.0. If you have both folders then reference your solution dll with v1.0 assembly.

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan dear I did so now but nothing changed still have the same problem

Comment: After changing the dll reference try after restart your visual studio

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan still the same

Comment: I'm having a warning msg : Warning 2 Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. In Visual Studio, double-click this warning (or select it and press Enter) to fix the conflicts; otherwise, add the following binding redirects to the "runtime" node in the application configuration file: <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Razor" culture="neutral"  ....

Comment: Try changing this `<add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0" />` to this `<add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />`. I believe that version 2.0.0.0 is what MVC 3 projects should be using, which implies you will need to use `System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0`. You can always create a new MVC 3 project from scratch and check the web.config of that project; compare it against your broken site.